# productsRequest delegate is not getting called?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Issue is that same things is working in another app.

What I am doing

```
#pragma mark SKProductsRequest
  -(void)requestProduct{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Connecting store..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
    _productRequest= [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:   [NSSet setWithObject: Product_100_CREDITS]];
    _productRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productRequest start];
  }
```

But for same Product identifier, one app works good and in another I get 'Cannot connect to iTunes Store'.  I am testing it in Simulater iOS 7.0

Comment: This problem is fixed now. requestProduct does not called in iOS7 simulater. It works in iOS6 Simulater. Thanks all

Comment: You should check in-App purchases in device. I got these kind of issues on simulator but in device they works like a charm. Hope it helps!